# Can I force the Linux kernel to be more aggresive keeping free RAM

Tags: nginx, memory, kernel

Is there a way to tell the kernel to keep a certain amount of free RAM and do not use it for caches?

I hear you thinking, "Why you would want that?! cached RAM is free RAM when someone wants it!"

This is a special case. It seems that a nginx plugin for an ip location service check the amount of free ram before reload and it refuses to restart / reload if there's not enough strictly free RAM to do it. And I have a couple of servers in this situation... all RAM cached and a nginx that refuses to restart itself. So I have to manually (or "cronly") do a drop_caches to have enough strict free RAM for the nginx restart.

I'd like to have a way to specify a max amount of cached ram or a minimum strict free RAM to keep available to get rid of the hacky drop_caches method

Comment: The best approach is to fix the broken nginx plugin, of course.

Comment: Not directly related, but you might also be interested in tweaking the "swappiness" setting.  That tells Linux how aggressively to swap pages to disk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness

Comment: I don't think you want to do that. Caches are really valuable, and can be released immediately when required. You need to fix the plugin. A temporary workaround could be to change php-fpm to "ondemand" rather than "dynamic" or "static", but this will reduce performance. Better slow than down though. https://ma.ttias.be/a-better-way-to-run-php-fpm/

Comment: It is not fpm is a C plugin, and it is beyond my ability to fix it. This is it -> https://github.com/chaizhenhua/ngx-ip2location and I traced the error up to a library it uses.

Comment: @theist have you made any attempt to submit a bug request to that project or communicate with the project owner?  They would almost certainly be in a much better position to help you with problems for that project.